# Chrome extension sending message from the content script to an html file after post ajax call receives its response

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a chrome extension where in I want the content script to pass the response of my post request to the html in extension.How to perform this as I am new for creating a chrome extension.

Comment: Sounds like you want to intercept the post request made by the page where your content script runs - see [Scrape / eavesdrop AJAX data using JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/a/13768794)

Comment: No this is not what I am looking for @wOxxOm. I just want to display my content script ajax request's response to the html.

Comment: The popup declared as browser_action in manifest.json? It runs only when it's shown so it would make more sense to perform the jquery request directly in your popup script.

Comment: I have a content script.js where I have made a jquery post request to which I get a response message from my server. Now I want this message to be shown in my html.How to have a interaction between content.js and my html(i.e the box which gets shown when the chrome extension is activated for a page just like the below popup.html file of this link .This is just a screenshot of the link (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)  https://nimb.ws/tlcQxN

Comment: Yeah, and I say you don't need a content script for this task. Simply load popup.js in your popup.html using `<script src="popup.js"></script>` and use the standard DOM methods. The popup is a separate page, it's not related to the web page so you don't need content scripts.

Comment: popup is declared in page_action not in browser_action.I know maybe they both are same

Comment: Yeah they're basically the same.